# Proof of Proper Subset in a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose V is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\dim V = 3$ and let $T: V \mapsto V$ be a linear transformation which satisfies $T^3 = 0$ and $T^2 \ne 0$ . I want to prove that $\ker T \subset \ker T^2$ (specifically, that $\ker T$ is a proper subset of $\ker T^2$ ).

Proving that $\ker T$ is a subset of $\ker T^2$ (not necessarily proper) is easy. We just consider an arbitrary $v \in \ker T \implies Tv = 0_V \implies T^2v = T(Tv) = T(0_V) = 0_V \implies v \in \ker T^2$ .

It is the condition that $\ker T \ne \ker T^2$ which has me stumped. I believe I have somewhat of a solution with the following proof by contradiction:

Assume that $\ker T = \ker T^2$ . This implies that $\forall u \in V$ , $T^2 u = 0_V \implies Tu = 0_V$ . Since $T^2 u = T(Tu)$ , this would mean that $T$ is one-to-one. However, we are given that $T^3 u = T(T^2 u) = 0_V$ when $T^2 u \ne 0_V$ , which means that $T$ is not one-to-one. We have reached a contradiction, so $\ker T \ne \ker T^2$ .

But I do not feel this is a strong enough proof. Is there a way to prove this without having to consider whether $T$ is one-to-one?

Comment: $\ker T^2=\ker T$ does not imply that $T$ is injective, and you have not reached a contradiction.

Comment: Your proof is actually fine. The only issue is that you did not prove that $T$ is one-to-one, but that $T|\operatorname{Im}(T)$ is one-to-one. However, that is enough since $T^2u\in\operatorname{Im}(T)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $T$ and $T^2$ annihilate the same vectors in all of $V$, then a fortiori they annihilate the same vectors in the range of $T.$ So $\ker T^2=\ker T^3.$

More explicitly, $\ker T^2=\ker T$ means that $T^2v = 0$ iff $Tv=0.$ Then for any $u$, $Tu$ is in $\ker T,$ iff it is in $\ker T^2.$ So $T^2(Tu)=0$ iff $T(Tu)=0.$ Thus $\ker T^3 = \ker T^2.$

But if $T^3=0$, then the kernel of $T^3$ is the whole space, and so is that of $T^2,$ but $T^2\neq 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Appreciate it. This makes sense. So, just to confirm, it is not correct to state that $T$ is injective, but taking the reasoning to $\ker T^3 = \ker T^2$ will directly address the problem, correct?

Comment: @K.Jiang Right, it is not correct to conclude that $T$ is injective; it need not be. Are you familiar with projection operators? They are idempotent, they satisfy $P^2=P$, but they are typically very far from injective. Showing that you can left-cancel $T$ for some vectors does not mean you can left cancel $T$ for all vectors, which is what injective means. Moving up in powers to connect to $T^3$ is the right approach.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is some problem. You have written that since $T^2 = T(Tu)$, this implies that $T$ is one-one. This statement stands on contentious ground.

Suppose that $a = T^2(b) \neq 0$, so that $b \neq 0$. This is by non-triviality of $T^2$. Note that $T(Tb) \neq 0$, since $a = T(Tb)$ is non-zero. However, $T^2(Tb) = Ta = 0$. So, $Tb \in \ker T^2$, but $Tb \notin \ker T$, showing strict containment.

Comment: @K.Jiang This post has been downvoted. If it was you, I would like to know why. Otherwise, you can ignore this.

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted this; in fact, I upvoted it. This is a great solution; thank you very much

Comment: @K.Jiang You are welcome. I was just clarifying, since I did not find anything wrong.